# android httpsurlconnection onclick

Tags: java, android, httpsurlconnection

I'm beginning my adventure with android and trying make app which will download data from website after logging in. I have written method to connecting with website in this way:

```
public class ConnectWebsite extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
String server_response;
public static final int CONNECTON_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 60000;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String result = "";
    InputStream is = null;
    URL url;
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(strings[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTON_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(CONNECTON_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("HTTP error code: " + responseCode);
        }
        is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if (is != null) {
            // Converts Stream to String with max length of 500.
            result = readStream(is, 500);
        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.d("ConnectWebsite ", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        Log.d("ConnectWebsite ", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
private String readStream(InputStream stream, int maxLength) throws IOException {
 ...
}
```

Unfortunately, when debugger will come to urlConnection.connect() App throw exception "Could not execute method for android:onClick"

EDIT: 
Fuction which services onclick

```
  public void login(View w){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Login...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ConnectWebsite conn = new ConnectWebsite();
    String url = "http://examplewebsite.com";
    conn.execute(url);
}
```

EDIT V2:

It almost works good, I had to declare uses-permission in manifest like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="myProject">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: Show the on click listener code. Especially how you call your asynctask. I think you use .get() on it. Put code in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: Ok, i edited my post

Comment: If you post the full error stack trace it would be more helpful

Comment: I am sorry that I haven't been answering for few hours, but I was busy. Before I added post I had changed code. I have invoked tasksync via .doInBackground instead via .execute and I declared permission in manifest.